# Can't get element by index after map in scala

Tags: scala

I try to do this in one line:

```
val data = Seq(1,2,3).map(i=>i)
val first = data(0)
```

Why can't I do

```
val first = (Seq(1,2,3).map(i=>i))(0)
```

The above statement gives a

> Error:(13, 40) type mismatch;  found   : Int(0)  required:
>   scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int],Int,?]
>       val first = (Seq(1,2,3).map(i=>i))(0)

Strangely, this works just fine:

```
val first = (Seq(1,2,3).map(i=>i)).apply(0)
```

Comment: In this case you could just do `Seq(1,2,3).map(i=>i).head`

Comment: For whatever reason I think your errant example is using [this `apply` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L435-L440) rather than the "accessor" `apply` method. I am guessing there is some implicit making that decision

Comment: I admit this is not obvious :) It's because `map` actually has a second parameter list that's implicit, so normally the compiler provides the parameters. However, when you give the `(0)` explicitly, the compiler tries to use this for the impllcit parameter and you get the type mismatch. The easiest way around it is just to use your first form and two statements. Your third one works because again the second argument list is omitted, sot he compiler provides it, and calls `apply` on the result of the map

Comment: See here https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/FilterMonadic.scala#L1 for the `map` declaration

Comment: @evan058 I'm aware that I can use head to get the first element, but what if I want another index?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I figured as much, just thought I would throw it out there.